# How to improve a "WHERE NOT EXIST" query for a big mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

I wrote this query which works absolutely perfect but since the database started growing this query became slower and slower until now where it almost takes 54 seconds to execute. Is there any way to improve this query to make it faster as I don't want this 54 to get any longer.

```
SELECT 
        twitter.user_id AS id
        FROM twitter
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  stats.id
                FROM    stats
                WHERE   stats.user_id = twitter.user_id AND stats.created_on >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                )
        GROUP BY twitter.id
        LIMIT 0 , 300
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on `stats.user_id, twitter.user_id, stats.created_on` ?

Comment: I just added indexes on them, would this solve it?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you Abhik! If you would like to answer this question I will vote it as solved

Comment: run the query and see what you get.. also you can use `explain` to see how the query is doing and using indexes

Comment: Try using joins over not exists it is a bit faster. You will need to have index on stats (user_id, created_on).   And another solution you could create a temporary table with engine=memory and btree index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your fields are missing indexes, so I would suggest to add indexes on joining columns and the date field

SO you may need to add indexes on

```
stats.user_id
twitter.user_id
stats.created_on
```

You can use `explain` to see how the query is doing, it will tell you which all indexes are used in the query.